# Create View SQL server in dbeaver 21.3.2 from temporary tables

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables, materialized-views, dbeaver

I have this queries in sql server . I´m using dbeaver 21.3.2 :

```
select YEARWEEK_DATE , art_name, YEARMONTH_DATE,
branchid as BRANCHID, ubicacion as UBICACION,banner  as BANNER, CCODIGO_CI ,art_matriz ,descripcion ,
codigoProveedor , marca ,clase , Categoria , Sub_Categoria , Coleccion , Matriz , Genero , Familia , talle,
Calidad , Precio_Costo_SIN_DESCUENTO , PRECIO_COSTO_CON_DESCUENTO , PDV_Dexter , PDV_StockCenter ,PDV_Moov ,
PDV_NikeShops ,PDV_eDexter , PDV_eMeli , PDV_eMoov , PDV_ESTOCK_CENTER , cantidad as unidades_vendidas, 
Venta_Neta as Venta_Neta , 0 AS STOCK, 'MTD' as REPORTE
into #temp_ventas_RSCV
from dabra.dbo.bi_tbl_tablero_ventas
where YEARMONTH_DATE 
like (select concat(CAST(year(GETDATE()) AS Varchar), right('0' + convert(varchar,datepart(mm,getdate())),2)))
and clase in ('ACCESORIOS', 'CALZADO', 'INDUMENTARIA')
and branchid not in ('872', '401')
and art_name is not NULL;

select YEARWEEK_DATE , art_name, YEARMONTH_DATE,
branchid as BRANCHID, ubicacion as UBICACION,banner  as BANNER, CCODIGO_CI ,art_matriz ,descripcion ,
codigoProveedor , marca ,clase , Categoria , Sub_Categoria , Coleccion , Matriz , Genero , Familia , talle,
Calidad , Precio_Costo_SIN_DESCUENTO , PRECIO_COSTO_CON_DESCUENTO , PDV_Dexter , PDV_StockCenter ,PDV_Moov ,
PDV_NikeShops ,PDV_eDexter , PDV_eMeli , PDV_eMoov , PDV_ESTOCK_CENTER ,0 AS unidades_vendidas, 
 0 AS Venta_Neta ,cantidad_stock as STOCK , 'MTD' as REPORTE
into #temp_stock_RSCV
from dabra.dbo.bi_tbl_tablero_stock btts 
where YEARMONTH_DATE 
like (select concat(CAST(year(GETDATE()) AS Varchar), right('0' + convert(varchar,datepart(mm,getdate())),2)))
and clase in ('ACCESORIOS', 'CALZADO', 'INDUMENTARIA')
and branchid not in ('872', '401')
and art_name is not NULL;

select t1.* 
into #tmp_intermedia
from
(Select * 
from #temp_ventas_RSCV
union all
select *
from #temp_stock_RSCV)t1;

select cast(YEAR (GETDATE())as int) as YEAR_DATE,  cast(RIGHT(YEARWEEK_DATE , 2)as int) as WEEK_DATE,
cast(YEAR (GETDATE()) as varchar) + cast(RIGHT(YEARWEEK_DATE , 2) as varchar) as PERIODO , YEARMONTH_DATE ,
branchid as BRANCHID,ubicacion AS UBICACION,banner AS BANNER, CCODIGO_CI , art_name as ART_NAME , art_matriz as ART_MATRIZ,
descripcion AS DESCRIPCION,codigoProveedor AS CODIGOPROVEEDOR ,talle as TALLE, marca AS MARCA, 
clase AS CLASE , Categoria AS CATEGORIA, Sub_Categoria AS SUB_CATEGORIA , Coleccion AS COLECCION , Matriz AS MATRIZ , 
Genero AS GENERO, Familia AS FAMILIA , Calidad AS CALIDAD , Precio_Costo_SIN_DESCUENTO AS PRECIO_COSTO_SIN_DESCUENTO,
PRECIO_COSTO_CON_DESCUENTO , PDV_Dexter AS PDV_DEXTER , PDV_StockCenter AS PDV_STOCKCENTER,PDV_Moov AS PDV_MOOV ,
PDV_NikeShops AS PDV_NIKESHOPS ,PDV_eDexter AS PDV_EDEXTER , PDV_eMeli AS PDV_EMELI , PDV_eMoov AS PDV_EMOOV , 
PDV_ESTOCK_CENTER AS PDV_ESTOCK_CENTER, sum(unidades_vendidas) AS UNIDADES_VENDIDAS, sum(Venta_Neta) AS VENTA_NETA, 
sum(STOCK) AS STOCK, REPORTE
INTO #PRE_VISTA
FROM #tmp_intermedia
group by  art_matriz,talle,
branchid,ubicacion ,banner , CCODIGO_CI ,descripcion ,codigoProveedor  , marca , 
clase  , Categoria , Sub_Categoria  , Coleccion  , Matriz  , Genero , Familia  , Calidad  , Precio_Costo_SIN_DESCUENTO ,
PRECIO_COSTO_CON_DESCUENTO , PDV_Dexter , PDV_StockCenter ,PDV_Moov ,PDV_NikeShops  ,PDV_eDexter  , 
PDV_eMeli  , PDV_eMoov  , PDV_ESTOCK_CENTER , REPORTE, YEARMONTH_DATE,YEARWEEK_DATE,art_name;

select t1.YEAR_DATE,t1.WEEK_DATE,t1.PERIODO ,t1.YEARMONTH_DATE  ,t1.BRANCHID,t1.UBICACION,  
t1.BANNER,t1.CCODIGO_CI,t1.ART_NAME, t1.ART_MATRIZ, t1.DESCRIPCION  ,t1.CODIGOPROVEEDOR ,t1.TALLE,t1.MARCA,
t2.FULL_NAME as PROVEEDOR,t1.CLASE,t1.CATEGORIA ,t1.SUB_CATEGORIA,  t1.COLECCION    ,t1.MATRIZ  ,t1.GENERO, 
t1.FAMILIA,t1.CALIDAD,t1.PRECIO_COSTO_SIN_DESCUENTO ,t1.PRECIO_COSTO_CON_DESCUENTO  ,t1.PDV_DEXTER, 
t1.PDV_STOCKCENTER,t1.PDV_MOOV,t1.PDV_NIKESHOPS,t1.PDV_EDEXTER  ,t1.PDV_EMELI,t1.PDV_EMOOV,
t1.PDV_ESTOCK_CENTER,t1.UNIDADES_VENDIDAS,t1.VENTA_NETA,t1.STOCK,t1.REPORTE
FROM #PRE_VISTA t1
left join tbl_dim_Netsuite_Entity t2
on t1.codigoProveedor = t2.ENTITY_ID;
```

I need a View from the last query in order to get data from a scheduled task in  a .py, but I´ve been reading and seems to be no chance to get a view from #temp.tables. What Could I do? is tehere another way? I haven´t enough experience with sql...If someone could give me a tip   to investigate Iy will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just don't use a temp table - use a regular table.

Comment: Hi Stu.. I can't create regular tables at work. I 'm not allowed. I can only use temp and views.

Comment: Can you create permanent tables in tempdb though?

Comment: No... Only views and temps at DB  where tables are. Sp I m allowed too

Comment: _I need a View from the last query in order to get data from a scheduled task in a .py._ Not sure why you're even trying to use #temp tables for this, let alone wanting to create a view on them. #temp tables are visible only to the current connection and will be disposed of automatically by SQL Server when they go out of scope. A scheduled task running in a different process, on a different connection, would not be able to see the #temp tables even if you held open the connection that created them.

Comment: that's why I need a View...to query the view from .py... but I don´t know how to create the view If I ´m not allowed to create regular tables...